# Java: Right Click Copy Cut Paste On TextField

Tags: java, swing

I've made a program which prints a value in a text field. The problem is that when a user right clicks in the text field, a menu like this won't open:

[image]

Is there a way the user can have this menu open upon right click?

This is my code:

```
public class A extends JFrame{
private JTextField txt1;
private JTextField txt2;
private JLabel val;
private JLabel prt;
private JButton bt1;


    public A() {

    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    txt1 = new JTextField();
    txt1.setBounds(178, 93, 87, 28);
    getContentPane().add(txt1);


    txt2 = new JTextField();
    txt2.setBounds(178, 148, 87, 28);
    getContentPane().add(txt2);


    val = new JLabel("Enter Value");
    val.setBounds(84, 93, 69, 28);
    getContentPane().add(val);

    prt = new JLabel("Printed Value");
    prt.setBounds(80, 148, 87, 28);
    getContentPane().add(prt);



    bt1 = new JButton("Click This");
    bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        int n=Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
        txt2.setText(n+"");


        }
    });
    bt1.setBounds(178, 188, 105, 28);
    getContentPane().add(bt1);

        setSize(400, 399);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);   

    }
}
```

Main Method:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        A object = new A(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Menus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) for the basics of creating a popup menu.

Then you can use the `Actions` provided by the `DefaultEditorKit` to create your popup menu.

For the "Delete" action you will need to create your own custom Action. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for the basics. Except you would extend `TextAction` since it has methods that allow you to access the text component with focus so you can create reusable code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class TextFieldPopup extends JPanel
{
    public TextFieldPopup()
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        add( textField );

        JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
        Action cut = new DefaultEditorKit.CutAction();
        cut.putValue(Action.NAME, "Cut");
        cut.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control X"));
        menu.add( cut );

        Action copy = new DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction();
        copy.putValue(Action.NAME, "Copy");
        copy.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"));
        menu.add( copy );

        Action paste = new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction();
        paste.putValue(Action.NAME, "Paste");
        paste.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control V"));
        menu.add( paste );

        Action selectAll = new SelectAll();
        menu.add( selectAll );

        textField.setComponentPopupMenu( menu );
    }

    static class SelectAll extends TextAction
    {
        public SelectAll()
        {
            super("Select All");
            putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control S"));
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
            component.selectAll();
            component.requestFocusInWindow();
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextFieldPopup");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TextFieldPopup() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yyou don't need the accelerators for cut, copy and paste as those are the defaults. Ctrl+S will not work for the Select All since accelerators only work for visible components on  a GUI. Ctrl+S will only work when the popup is visible. I defined the accelerator in the Action because an Action can also be in a JButton, in which case the accelerator would work. I guess the accelerator should be removed from the Action since it is misleading because it doesn't really work like other shortcuts. You could leave the cut, copy, paste accelerators since they do work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason extending a JPanel is better than extending the JTextField itself?

Answer (score 5):

Static class to instantly add regular popup menu to a textfield.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.undo.*;


public class JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu {
    public static void addTo(JTextField txtField) 
    {
        JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        UndoManager undoManager = new UndoManager();
        txtField.getDocument().addUndoableEditListener(undoManager);

        Action undoAction = new AbstractAction("Undo") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (undoManager.canUndo()) {
                    undoManager.undo();
                }
                else {
                   System.out.println("No Undo Buffer.");
                }
            }
        };

       Action copyAction = new AbstractAction("Copy") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.copy();
            }
        };

        Action cutAction = new AbstractAction("Cut") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.cut();
            }
        };

        Action pasteAction = new AbstractAction("Paste") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.paste();
            }
        };

        Action selectAllAction = new AbstractAction("Select All") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                txtField.selectAll();
            }
        };

        cutAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control X"));
        copyAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control C"));
        pasteAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control V"));
        selectAllAction.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control A"));

        popup.add (undoAction);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add (cutAction);
        popup.add (copyAction);
        popup.add (pasteAction);
        popup.addSeparator();
        popup.add (selectAllAction);

       txtField.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
JTextFieldRegularPopupMenu.addTo(jTxtMsg);
```

Instantly adds popup menu to the chosen JTextFIeld.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with [How to use menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) and [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup) (although I'd personally use [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)) instead of a `MouseListener`)

Then I'd have a look at [`JTextField#copy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy()), [`JTextField#cut`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#cut()) and [`JTextField#paste`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#paste())